# How to run two Kubernetes master without worker node , the first k8s and 2nd k8s replication mode

Tags: kubernetes

How to run two kubernetes master without worker node ,one k8s master another should work as slave ,?

Answer (score 0):

You can find 2 solution for **Creating Highly Available clusters with kubeadm** [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/).

There are described steps in order to create 2 kinds kinds of cluster:

- Stacked control plane and etcd nodes
- External etcd nodes

Additional resources:

- [Install and configure a multi-master Kubernetes cluster with kubeadm - HAProxy as a load balancer](https://blog.inkubate.io/install-and-configure-a-multi-master-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm/)
- [kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)

Hope this help.